# Hide Bootstrap 5 Modal before .show() is finished

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

In Bootstrap 5 calling `Modal.hide()` has no effect unless it occurs after the modal has finished the fade/transition effect.

By removing the `fade` class the `hide` method acts instantly.

How can I achieve that, while keeping the fade effect?

In the below example, clicking on a button will show information about that item in a the modal. Suppose you accidentally clicked on the wrong button, you should be able to back-out (cancel the `.show()`) immediately so you can click on the correct button.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Modal Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Buttons -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary item-button" data-item-info="You clicked # 1">
        Item # 1
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary item-button" data-item-info="You clicked # 2">
        Item # 2
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary item-button" data-item-info="You clicked # 3">
        Item # 3
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), {
            keyboard: false
        })

        $('.item-button').click(function(){
            $('#myModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).data('item-info'))
            myModal.show();
        })

        $('.modal').click(function(e){
            if(!$(e.target).hasClass("modal-body")){
                myModal.hide();
            }
        })

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried

Comment: @Zim I don't have any idea what I should try. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Removing classes with your own code (outside of Bootstrap’s code) could cause problems as the flags that Boostrap uses (e.g. `_isShown` and `_isTransitioning` won’t get updated. You could use the `show.bs.modal` to prevent the modal from ever showing or the `shown.bs.modal` event to call `hide()` to transition the modal as soon as it appears. *Note: the show event doesn’t work in BS 5.0.1, but there’s a fix in for the next release, 5.0.2.*

Comment: Add the code that to help us reproduce the issue. Where is the modal markup? Where is the JS code call modal.hide()?

Comment: @Zim Updated. I didn't include code because I don't think it's related to my specific implementation but generally just canceling/interrupting the `.show()` at any time. I think this should be the default behaviour if `.hide()` is called manually. I can see how it would be a problem if a user double clicks the triggering element, causing the modal to never show. So I think, this should be the default only if `.hide()` is called programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

### Update – blocking or hiding a modal

To respond to your latest comment — *how to cancel Modal.show() early* — I don’t believe you can *cancel* a modal being shown “early”.

You can either *block* a model from displaying at all — returning `preventDefault()` to the `show.bs.modal` event (this currently only works once, after which you can can’t open the modal, but that should be [fixed](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/34085) in version 5.0.2).

Or you can *wait* for the modal to be displayed using the `shown.bs.modal` event and then tell it to hide.

When the modal gets the okay to open (the show.bs.modal event doesn’t return `preventDefault`), two values are set to true, `this._isShown` and `this.isTransitioning` . Until the modal is fully displayed, you can’t use hide() as those two values are checked in the [hide() function] https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/js/src/modal.js#L146) and a hide request will be ignored until the modal is shown and no longer transitioning.

Bootstrap 5 code

```
hide(event) {
    if (event && ['A', 'AREA'].includes(event.target.tagName)) {
      event.preventDefault()
    }

    if (!this._isShown || this._isTransitioning) {
      return
    }
```

If you decide you want to hide the modal for whatever reason while the modal is transitioning, you can wait for the `shown.bs.modal` event and then call the hide from there. If you need to know whether the modal is showing or transitioning or whatever, you could use some variables to track that (setting the variables from the show and shown listeners and unsetting them from the hide and hidden listeners.

```js
var standardModal1 = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("standardModal1"), {
    keyboard: false
});

var standardModal2 = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("standardModal2"), {
    keyboard: false
});

document.getElementById('standardModal1').addEventListener("show.bs.modal", function(event) {
    return event.preventDefault();
});

document.getElementById('standardModal2').addEventListener("shown.bs.modal", function(event) {
    standardModal2.hide();
});
```

```css
.item-button {
    width: 10rem;
    height: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <button type="button" id="btnFour" class="btn btn-primary item-button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#standardModal1">
                preventDefault
            </button>

            <button type="button" id="btnfive" class="btn btn-primary item-button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#standardModal2">
                Hide after shown
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Standard Modal block -->
<div class="modal fade" id="standardModal1" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="standardModal1Label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="standardModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                You clicked preventDefault
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Standard Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="standardModal2" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="standardModal2Label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="standardModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                You clicked Hide after shown
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to run the preventDefault modal a second time, you’ll need to reload the page.

Comment: The thing is, any delay at all between hide call causes problems is my use case, because I'm doing other things that depend on the modal being closed.

Comment: To be specific, I want the modal to close when user hits browser back button. I do this by updating the URL when the modal is shown. When user hits back button or someway closes modal, I do history.go(-1). Now the problem is, if the user triggers the hide action and history.go(-1) is called but Modal.hide hasn't responded. So the user's history is set to previous page but modal is just finished showing. Now if user hits back again, it's like history.go(-2), it completely breaks the UX.

Comment: Manipulating the browser history is a different category of question from Bootstrap 5. You might want to repost your question and include the details about what you’re trying to do with the browser history when a modal is shown, along with your code that “completely breaks the UX.”

Comment: This is why I didn't get into specifics because it complicates the question. Which is simply, how to cancel Modal.show() early. No matter how I reask the question, it will not solve the underlying issue, which is that the `hide()` method ignores calls.

Comment: The solution is to change `if (!this._isShown || this._isTransitioning)` to  `if (!this._isShown)` at line 151: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/js/src/modal.js#L151
I've proposed this solution on github.

Answer (score 0):

Rich DeBourke correctly points out in his answer that the hide() function in Bootstraps modal.js returns early if it is in a transitioning state:

```js
class Modal extends BaseComponent {
  //...
  hide() {
    if (!this._isShown || this._isTransitioning) {
      return
    }
    //...
  }
}
```

As a work around you may be able call the modal's `dispose()` method instead:

```js
function hideExistingModal(targetEl) {
    if (targetEl) {
        var modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(targetEl);
        if(modal){
            modal._isTransitioning ? modal.dispose() : modal.hide();
        }
    }
}
```

The `dispose()` function is more heavy handed and will *throw an exception* if the modal is in a transitioning state - but it will give the desired outcome.

An error is thrown due to the `_isAnimated()` function being called after a timeout - which attempts to reference the modal that no longer exists. Unfortunatley this means it will always throw an exception as the only time `dispose()` is called is when the modal is transitioning.

This workaround gives the functionality required at the expense of an ugly console error.

Hopefully the requirement on `this._isTransitioning` being false is removed in future versions so this ugly workaround doesn't have to be used.